# Component clean up fails between tests with Vue test-utils

Tags: vue.js, code-cleanup, vue-test-utils

I have a simple component (HelloComponent) and a couple of tests. First test shallow mounts the component, prints it (wrapper of the component) on the console, and finally calls `destroy()` api on it. And the second test just prints it without mounting it. I was `expecting the second test to print undefined` but it prints the same thing (full component markup) as first test. Is my expectation incorrect ?

```
<!-- HelloComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        Hello {{name}}!
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    export default {
        name: 'Hello',
        data() {
            return {
                name: ''
            };
        },
        methods: {
            setName(name) {
                this.name = name;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import HelloComponent from '@/HelloComponent.vue';

describe('Hello component unit tests', () => {
  let wrapper;

  describe('Set 1', () => {
    it('should load component', () => {
        wrapper = shallowMount(HelloComponent, {});
        expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
        wrapper.vm.setName('oomer');
        console.log(wrapper.html());
        wrapper.destroy();
    });
  });

  describe('Set 2', () => {
    it('should log empty component', () => {
      expect(wrapper.vm.name).toEqual('oomer');
      console.log(wrapper.html());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: in fact, if i print, via `console.log(wrapper.html())`, the component markup on a new line right after `wrapper.destroy();` even in the first test, it still prints the full component markup.

Comment: According to the [implementation of the destroy method](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/blob/dev/packages/test-utils/src/wrapper.js#L164), I guess your expectation is wrong. The element will be removed from its parent node and the component (wrapper.vm) gets destroyed. Since the wrapper is still holding a reference to the element, the [html method](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/blob/dev/packages/test-utils/src/wrapper.js#L363) still returns the markup.

Comment: What are you trying to test, anyway?

Comment: @PhilipWeinke to your first comment, i updated the tests to check if wrapper.vm really gets destroyed but my second test passes (check it out) :(. Howcome it retains the name value that was set in first test ?

Comment: I'm not familar with the vue internals. I had a brief look into the destroy method and while it does quite some things, it doesn't reset the name. I still have no idea what you want to achieve with your tests.

Comment: @oomer You have to reset the `wrapper` between tests: Move `wrapper = shallowMount(...)` into `beforeEach()`.